# Вывод измененной строки

Tags: ассемблер

Задание следующие: нужно написать EXE программу которая выводит строку "Input string", за тем изменить эту строку так чтобы первую и последнюю букву строки изменить на строчную, а остальные на прописные. Реализовал программу которая выводит все буквы прописными а как сделать так как в задании не знаю(Есть идея сделать сначала чтобы только первую букву строки менять на строчную в цикле, а потом последнюю но только не знаю сработает ли это и как реализовать)

```
.model tiny
.data
 Sos db "Input string $"  
 len dw $-Sos
 .code
 main proc
    
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx,offset Sos
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h    
 mov cx,len
 lst:
 mov di,cx
 cmp Sos[di+0],60h 
 jl next 
 sub Sos[di+0],20h 
 next:
 loop lst 
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx, offset Sos 
 mov ah,09h
 int 21h 
 mov ax,4c00h
 int 21h

 main endp
 end main
 code ends
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ; Строка должна заканчиваться $ и не должна полностью состоять из пробелов
 mov ds,ax
 mov dx,offset Sos
 xor di, di
NextSymbol:
 cmp [dx][di], ' '
 jne Symbol1ToUpper
 inc di
 jmp NextSymbol
Symbol1ToUpper:
 sub [dx][di], Число ; Преобразовать в верхний/нижний регистр

 xor di, di
CheckForEndStr:    
 cmp [dx][di], '$'
 je FoundEndOfStr
 inc di
 jmp CheckForEndStr
FoundEndOfStr:
 dec di
 cmp [dx][di], ' '
 je FoundEndOfStr
 sub [dx][di], Число ; Преобразовать в верхний/нижний регистр
```

Comment: Спасибо большое